# Writing values in hash to an array in a specific order

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

So I have a bunch of hashes that look like this

```
{
 "key1"=>"value1", 
 "key2"=>"value2", 
 "key4"=>"value4"
}

{
 "key1"=>"value1", 
 "key3"=>"value3", 
 "key4"=>"value4"
}
```

As you can see, not all of the hashes have all of the keys. Out of this, I need to get an array with all of the values, and the string "Not listed" in place of all of the missing values.

I started writing some code like this:

```
result = []
i = 0
hash.each do |key, value|
    i+=1
    result << value if key == "key" + i.to_s
end
```

before I realized that this strategy was not going to work. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Expected output for the first hash would be

```
["value1", "value2", "Not Listed", "value4"]
```

and for the second hash would be

```
["value1", "Not Listed", "value3", "value4"]
```

Comment: expected output ? show me ...

Comment: What sort of data size are you working with here? Hundreds? Thousands? Millions?

Comment: Hundreds of thousands to a million each time I run the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not clear how you know how many keys there should be, but assuming you should have 4 keys, you could do the following:

```
h = {
 "key1"=>"value1", 
 "key2"=>"value2", 
 "key4"=>"value4"
}
(1..4).map { |i| h["key#{i}"] || 'Not Listed' }
#=> ["value1", "value2", "Not Listed", "value4"]
```

Arup suggested a different flavor, using `fetch`:

```
(1..4).map { |i| h.fetch("key#{i}", 'Not Listed') }
#=> ["value1", "value2", "Not Listed", "value4"]
```

Still another option is using `Hash`'s `default` value:

```
h.default = 'Not Listed'
(1..4).map { |i| h["key#{i}"] }
#=> ["value1", "value2", "Not Listed", "value4"]
```

Comment: Ruby way( I like most) - `(1..4).map { |i| h.fetch("key#{i}", 'Not Listed') }`

Comment: I was upset, first, now I see , you used `#fetch`. +1. I am happy,

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your hash with the default "not listed"  then iterate through your input to populate values that are present.

```
def solution(keys,default_val)
  Hash[keys.product([default_val])]
end
result = solution(["key1","key2", "key3", "key4"],"not listed")
hash.each do |key, value|
  result[key] = value 
end

print(result)
```

Sorry just copied what user had.

Comment: did you try to run this code? - it is not running correctly.

Comment: Sorry just copied what user had.